# Move subview of UIScrollView when smaller than its bounds

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimageview

In the regular Photos-app on your device, if you zoom all the way out, you are then unable to drag the image up and down. This is because there is nothing up there, so there's really no reason to be dragging when fully zoomed out. However, in my app I want this to work. It's sort of a cropper-tool, so I want the user to be able to zoom all the way out, and then some, and still be able to move the small image anywhere on the screen, but preferably not out of bounds to the point where you can't see it.

I kinda solved this earlier by adding the imageView as a subview to an invisible view that was 3 times larger than the imageView, and then adding this invisiView to the scrollView, however, this proved to be difficult to handle with the cropping. Anyway, I was wondering if there is a way to do this with the imageView as the only subview of the scrollView.

I want the user to be able to zoom out, and **move** the image like this, so it stays there:

```
 -----------------
|     ----        |
|    |    |       |
|    |    |       |
|     ----        |
|      ^imageView |
|                 |
|                 | <-- scrollView
|                 |
|                 |
|    *nothing*    |
|                 |
 -----------------
```

The zooming part isn't really the issue, that's just adjusting the minimumZoomScale to 0.1 or whatever, but whenever the image is smaller than the screen, I.E black border of nothingness around the entire image, it's now impossible to **move** the image. Initially, it was stuck in the top left, but I found a way to center it, but I would still like to be able to move it around.

Anyone?

Comment: what do u have set as for contentSize of the scrollView?

Comment: @TMacGyver Oh, I haven't set anything.. I'm guessing it turns into whatever size the image is. So, if I manually set contentSize to be double the size of the image, that should do it?

Comment: yea, i think that'll do it.  U should almost always explicitly set the contentSize for scrollViews

Comment: @TMacGyver - I tried it now, and you are clearly onto something here! In my `scrollViewDidZoom` I made the scrollView.contentSize be equal to the double of imageView.frame.size, but whenever I zoom now, the image pops out of the view. I suspect this is because I **SET** the value instead of incrementing it.. I'll test some more, then update my question. Thanks!